# Тень под картинкой, эффект 3д

Tags: html, jquery, css, html5

Есть сетка в изометрии. Вписываю туда картинку, типа 3д. Как лучше сделать тень под ней? Тень нужна типа  круг под ракетой

https://jsfiddle.net/ph593428/3/

Сама сетка изометрическая.

```js
function space_station() {
  var station_grid = 100;
  var $station_item;
  for (var i = 0; i < station_grid; i++) {
    $station_item = $("<div />", {
      class: 'st-item',
      id: 'st-i' + i
    });
    $(".station_wrapper").append($station_item);
  }
}

space_station();
```

```css
.station_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 12.5em;
  width: 12.5em;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 40%;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.station_wrapper .st-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  outline: 1px solid #cccccc;
  float: left;
}

.rocket {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  top: 125px;
  left: 325px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="space">
  <img class="rocket" src="http://digital-certificate.ru/1rocket.png" />
  <div class="station_wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно речь о фильтре: смотрим

Картинка не пашет на ruSO: [здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/1on3mzxr/) есть.

```js
function space_station() {
  var station_grid = 100;
  var $station_item;
  for (var i = 0; i < station_grid; i++) {
    $station_item = $("<div />", {
      class: 'st-item',
      id: 'st-i' + i
    });
    $(".station_wrapper").append($station_item);
  }
}

space_station();
```

```css
.station_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 12.5em;
  width: 12.5em;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 40%;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.station_wrapper .st-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  outline: 1px solid #cccccc;
  float: left;
}

.rocket {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  top: 125px;
  left: 325px;
  z-index: 100;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px rgba(100, 0, 0, 0.5));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="space">
  <img class="rocket" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJNlQ.png" />
  <div class="station_wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Тут немного не то, Вы даете пример свечения, я мне нужен будто круг под ракетой,как тень. Напимер, jsfidde когда грузится у него лого прыгает и там примерно такая тень, как мне нужна

Comment: @zkolya ни чего там не прыгает .... так и пишите следующий раз что надо что бы прыгало ....

Comment: @MonkeyMutant все-таки в `jsfiddle` логотип прыгает при загрузке

Answer (score 0):

Самый банальный способ:

Обернуть `img` с ракетой и добавить псевдо-элемент, с очень простой тенью.

```js
function space_station() {
  var station_grid = 100;
  var $station_item;
  for (var i = 0; i < station_grid; i++) {
    $station_item = $("<div />", {
      class: 'st-item',
      id: 'st-i' + i
    });
    $(".station_wrapper").append($station_item);
  }
}

space_station();
```

```css
.station_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 12.5em;
  width: 12.5em;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 40%;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.station_wrapper .st-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  outline: 1px solid #cccccc;
  float: left;
}

.rocket {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  top: 125px;
  left: 325px;
  z-index: 100;
}
.rocket img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.rocket::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: calc(25px / 2);
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.35);
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - (25px / 2));
  bottom: -5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="space">
  <div class="rocket">
    <img src="http://digital-certificate.ru/1rocket.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="station_wrapper"></div>
</div>
```